# Unicode character is written with wrong byteorder

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, binary

I'm trying to add byteorder mark to my string. But when I open the output file, my mark is reversed for some reason (0xFF 0xFE is written instead of 0xFE 0xFF). I wonder what could be the reason for such a behaviour...

```cs
if (Globals.target_encoding.WebName == "utf-16" && !isURLFrame) 
{ 
    BOM = '\uFEFF'+BOM; 
}
if (Globals.target_revision.number == 0x04) 
{ 
    processedString = BOM + source.text.Replace(Globals.target_separator.ToString(), '\0' + BOM) + '\0'; 
}
else 
{ 
    processedString = BOM + source.text + '\0'; 
};
if (!isURLFrame)
{
    contents = new byte[1 + Globals.target_encoding.GetByteCount(processedString)];
    contents[0] = targetEncodingValue(); // Тип кодировки
    Array.Copy(Globals.target_encoding.GetBytes(processedString), 0, contents, 1, Globals.target_encoding.GetByteCount(processedString));
}
else
{
    contents = new byte[Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(processedString)];
    Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(processedString), 0, contents, 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(processedString));
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce that to a [mcve] please? There are multiple branches there, but we don't know which ones need to be taken in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why reversed? You are using UTF-16? So both BOM FF FE and FE FF are correct (and the important part: consistent with the rest of file). If you want UTF-16BE or UTF16-LE you should know the bytorder of your architecture (or general trick to extrac bytes), and write them to the right order)

Comment: I'm writing a file using UTF16-LE

Comment: Would Globals.target_encoding.GetString(Globals.target_encoding.GetPreamble()) be better?

Comment: `FF FE` is correct for UTF-16 little-endian.